# How do i convert NSLog to string?

Tags: objective-c, nslog

I have the following code,

```
#define DLog(fmt, ...) NSLog((@"%s [Line %d] " fmt), __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__);
```

How do I convert NSLog output to a string so i can pass into log parameter? see below.

```
#define DLog(fmt, ...) [MyClass log:NSLogString];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't "...convert NSLog output to a string". NSLog sends its output to standard output. It does a file operation.

You should be able to use code like this:

```
void DLog(NSString* format, ...)
{
    va_list params_list;

    //Extract the variable-length list of parameters
    va_start(params_list, format);

    NSString *outputString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: format 
      arguments: params_list];

    //Now do what you want with your outputString

    //Now clean up the var_args.
    va_end(params_list);
}
```

The magic is the `NSString` `initWithFormat:arguments:` method, which takes a params_list extracted from var_args and returns a string. That's what you want.

Comment: i used #define for DLog, how do i use this method? where should i put it because i had DLog in .pch file before. Thank you.

Comment: It's not a macro, it is a different function to replace NSLog. You can put the definition in your .pch file if you want, or just make it a global function and create a .h file just like any other.

Comment: how do i put definition in .pch? can you give me an example, or link? Thank you.

Comment: The cleanest way is to create a .m and .h file with the DLog command declared in the .h, and then add a `#import DLog.h` in your .pch file.

Answer (score 0):

is this what you want?

```
#define DLog(...) NSLog(__VA_ARGS__)
```

Comment: what i want is when user call DLog macro, it send what is passed to a string.